# Shoot bullets diagonally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a spaceship which fires shots straight ahead. This works so far. But I want some shots that move diagonally, too.

This is the bullet-script:

```
public float damage = 25f;

float speed;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    speed = 8f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //get the bullet's current position
    Vector2 position = transform.position;

    //compute the bullet's new position
    position = new Vector2(position.x, position.y + speed * Time.deltaTime);

    //update the bullet's position
    transform.position = position;

    //this is the top right point of the screen
    Vector2 max = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(1, 1));

    //if the bullet went outside the screen on the top, then destroy the bullet
    if (transform.position.y > max.y) {
    // this is just an object-pool
        PlayerControl.bulletPool.ReturnInstance(gameObject);
    }
}
```

This is the playershoot-script:

```
public GameObject bulletPosition01;
public GameObject playerShotsGO;

void Update () {
    //fire bullets when the spacebar is pressed
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
        Shoot();
    }

//function to make the player shoot
public void Shoot () {
    //play the laser sound effect
    SoundManager.PlaySFX (shootAudio);

    //get bullet from object-pool
    GameObject bullet01 = bulletPool.GetInstance (playerShotsGO);
    bullet01.transform.position = bulletPosition01.transform.position;

    bullet01.transform.SetParent (playerShotsGO.transform, true);
}
```

Comment: try adding transform.up instead of constantly incrementing your y value only?

Comment: You would need to modify the x value of your bullet to have it go diagonally, just like on a graph in Algebra, when plotting slope, if the bullet is fired from 0, 0, on next update to bullet you add 1 to y, then you would also add 1 to x and that would cause it to move in a 45 degree angle

Comment: Thanks I'll try that ASAP.

Comment: The bullets fly diagonally but how do I turn them in the appropriate direction? The bullets look not in the same direction...

Answer (score 3):

This is not how to properly shoot a prefab. Use the built-in physics for this. Attach `Rigidbody` to your GameObject if it is a 3D Object. If it's a 2D Object, attach `Rigidbody2D`  to it. You use `Rigidbody.AddForce` or `Rigidbody.velcociy` to shoot the Object. To make it shoot the direction it is facing, use `transform.forward` and multiple it by some force.

A very basic 2D shooting script:

```
public float speed = 100;
//Assign from the Editor
public GameObject bulletPrefab;


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);
        ShootBullet(bullet);
    }
}

void ShootBullet(GameObject rb)
{
    Rigidbody2D bulletRb = rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    //The direction to shoot the bullet
    Vector3 pos = bulletRb.transform.forward * speed;
    //Shoot
    bulletRb.velocity = pos;
}
```

As *"Gunnar B"* [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023312/shoot-bullets-diagonally-in-unity/50023664#comment87065400_50023664), If shooting multiple (2) bullets from a spaceship then create two empty Objects on the side of the  spaceship you want the bullet to come out from. Also put those two Objects under the spaceship then use them as location to instantiate the bullet.

```
public float speed = 100;
//Assign bulletPrefab from the Editor
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
//Assign ship from the Editor
public Transform spaceShip;

//[Empty GameObject] Assign from the Editor
public Transform leftBarrel;
//[Empty GameObject] Assign from the Editor
public Transform rightBarrel;


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        //Instantiate left and right bullets
        GameObject leftBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, leftBarrel.position, spaceShip.rotation);
        GameObject rightBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, rightBarrel.position, spaceShip.rotation);

        //Shoot left and right bullets
        ShootBullet(leftBullet);
        ShootBullet(rightBullet);
    }
}

void ShootBullet(GameObject obj)
{
    Rigidbody2D bulletRb = obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    //The direction to shoot the bullet
    Vector3 pos = spaceShip.up * speed;
    //Shoot
    bulletRb.velocity = pos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.:)

Comment: Go ahead. Make sure to attach Rigidbody2D to the prefab and to also assign the bullet prefab to the "bulletPrefab" slot in the Editor otherwise you will get NullException errors.

Comment: To add to this: A simple and good way to have multiple "barrels" is to attach empty gameobjects to your spaceship facing the desired directions (acting as gunpoint) and spawning the bullets at their position and rotation (as parameters for instantiate).

Comment: Good advice. Missed the spaceship part and thought this is just for a 2D character.

Comment: Little fix: `spaceShip.rotation` should be `leftBarrel.rotation` (and rightBarrel respectivly) to account for rotated barrels. Same for in `ShootBullet`.

Comment: @GunnarB. The barrel is not really changing rotation like most spaceship games and is a child of the spaceship.It has a fixed rotation. The only thing we need from it is the position. Rotation should be rotation of the space ship. Maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Well, I would set it up rotated from the beginning (based on that OP is mentioning diagonal shooting). (Like one straight, one rotated a bit to the left and one a bit to the right or something like that.)

Comment: I think OP wanted to shoot the bullet where spaceship is facing instead of just upwards which is done with the `spaceShip.up` in my answer. Since OP hasn't made a comment since but is still here, I think it would be waste of our time to continue to help because you need feedback from OP to tell if the code is working or not then determine what to change or not.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. The spaceship doesn't rotate. It just flies straight ahead. Your code would work if my spaceship rotates but that's not the case. Another problem is that I cannot implement your code that easily because my game is based on another game's sourcecode which I got from a comprehensive video tutorial. Also I'm using an object pool (because of performance issues). That makes it a little bit more complicated. If I use it I have to revamp some of my code. I'll have a look at it tomorrow.:)

Comment: If you followed a tutorial and it's not working well, maybe you should reconsider the tutorial you are following. I saw the Object pooling stuff in your question and that has nothing to do with the problem in your question. I used instantiate to create a complete and compile-able solution for anyone that will see this answer and you can easily replace that line of code with your object pooling code. Finally, if you can't read what's in this answer and implement it easily then I don't know how else to help you. You can stick with that tutorial.

Comment: I tested your code and it didn't work very well. My game ran choppy and other things like enemies didn't work any more.